# Are Gradle dependencies less safe than downloading the jar to libs?

Tags: java, android, github, gradle

I want to have some graphing functionality in my Android app and found a few on Github. Most of them recommend including some URLs in the Gradle to serve as dependencies.

However what if the website goes down, or the author decides to remove the code? Does this break your app? Is it safer to download the premade .jar file to the lib folder so you have your own copy of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to use dependencies from well known repositories like Maven central. The rule is that once the artifact is uploaded it can't be changed or removed.